# ¿Como mostrar el tiempo de carga de una web con Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Estoy usando la función profiler de Codeigniter y me gustaría guardar esa información en un array y poder mostrarla.

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Actualmente me muestra la información sin diseño y no puedo controlarla, como mucho puedo ocultar algunos elementos:

```
$sections = array(
         'config'  => FALSE,
         'benchmarks'  => FALSE,
         'config'  => FALSE ...
}
```

Me interesa mucho obtener el execution time total de todas las querys que se ejecutan en cada sección de mi web y mostrarlo.

Algo como esto quiero conseguir:

```
Página cargada en 0.003 segundos.
```

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso lo puedes hacer por medio de [Benchmarking Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html) que `Codeigniter` te proporciona.

```
// Inicio
$this->benchmark->mark('code_start');

// Aqui va el código que quieres medir su tiempo de ejecución

// Fin
$this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

// Se imprime el tiempo de ejecucion entre code_start y code_end
echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end');
```

Esa es la manera mas simple de medir el tiempo haciendo uso del mismo `Codeigniter`.

Comment: Maravilloso! No lo conocía, gracias.